# MySQL query to count 1's occurrence in different columns of feedback table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count all the occurrence of '1' in the columns `commskill`, `abilityskill`, `interest`, `presentation`, `methodology`, `maintainsclass`, `punctual`, `attitude`.
My table 'Feedback' has following columns:

- Fid-feedback I'd
- Tname- teacher name
- Sname-subject name
- Studentname- students name
- Class- class of students
- Section - section of class
- commskill- communication skill
- abilityskill- ability of teaching
- Presentation - presentation skills of teacher
- Methodology - method for teaching followed by teacher
- Interest - interest of students in that teacher's class
- Punctual - time punctuality of teachers
- maintainsclass- maintains class discipline
- attitude - attitude of teacher towards students
  *tid- teacher 's ID

The values of fid are auto-increment,and grades of all skills are in(1-excellent, 2-good, 3-average,4-below average).

I've already tried this query:

```
select tname,sname,count(*) as excellent from feedback where commskill=1 or attitude =1 or presentation =1 or abilityskill=1 or interest=1 or punctual =1 or maintainsclass=1 or methodology =1 group by tid;
```

but the answer showed is unexpected and wrong.

Answer (score 2):

TO GET TOTAL occurrence of '1' in the columns commskill, abilityskill, interest, presentation, methodology, maintainsclass, punctual, attitude.

```
   SELECT
      sum(if(commskill=1,1,0)
    + sum(if(attitude =1,1,0)
    + sum(if(presentation =1,1,0)
    + sum(if(abilityskill=1,1,0)
    + sum(if(interest=1,1,0)
    + sum(if(punctual =1,1,0) 
    + sum(if(maintainsclass=1,1,0) 
    + sum(if(methodology =1,1,0)
   AS excellent
   FROM feedback;
```

to get results for each teacher

```
SELECT 
tname
, sname
, sum(if(commskill=1,1,0)
  + sum(if(attitude =1,1,0)
  + sum(if(presentation =1,1,0)
  + sum(if(abilityskill=1,1,0)
  + sum(if(interest=1,1,0)
  + sum(if(punctual =1,1,0) 
  + sum(if(maintainsclass=1,1,0) 
  + sum(if(methodology =1,1,0)
```

AS excellent
   FROM feedback
   GROUP BY tid ;